# Ionic alert - check if result is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I load a JSON file from a server with angular and Ionic.

This is my code:

```
$scope.showAlert = function(mo,di,mi,don,fr,sa,so) {
              $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Success',
                content: mo + "<br>" + di + "<br>" + mi + "<br>" + don + "<br>" + fr + "<br>" + sa+ "<br>" + so
              }).then(function(res) {
                console.log('Test Alert Box');
              });
            };
```

For the Item:

```
<i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline links" ng-click="showAlert(item.openingHours[0], item.openingHours[1], item.openingHours[2], item.openingHours[3],
  item.openingHours[4], item.openingHours[5], item.openingHours[6]
)"></i>
```

My Problem is that sometimes the results, for example item.openingHours[6] is undefined. I don't want a undefined text in my alert. How can I check if the value is undefined in the alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional (ternary) operator `?`, to check that `str` is defined, if defined return the value with `br`, if not - empty string:

```
$scope.showAlert = function(mo, di, mi, don, fr, sa, so) {
  function getStrWithBr(str) {
    return str ? str + '<br/>' : '';
  }
  var content = 
    getStrWithBr(mo) +
    getStrWithBr(di) + 
    getStrWithBr(mi) + 
    getStrWithBr(fr) + 
    getStrWithBr(sa) + 
    so || '';
 ...
```

Comment: Fixed, now `br` is added only when the value is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander !